# Add a .avi video in Beamer

Tags: beamer, media9, multimedia

I am trying to add a single video in a beamer presentation. I am using `\usepackage{multimedia}` and in my main code following code added for the video:

```latex
\begin{frame}{Movie}
\movie[showcontrols]{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{play.png}}{test19.avi}
\end{frame}
```

However in my pdf I get the image `play.png` and by clicking on it can't be able to play the video. What is my problem here?

Comment: The PDF viewer, probably. Which one do you use?

Comment: It is Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

Comment: The AVI file must reside in the same directory as the PDF.

Comment: Both the .avi video and generated pdf are in the same directory. But still its not working. Video can't able to play in the pdf.